# Is there a convenient way to express the continuous relaxation of a MIP using cvxpy?

Tags: python, cvxpy

I want to solve a (convex) mixed integer program as well as its continuous relaxation using cvxpy. Is there a way to use the same implementation of the objective and the constraints for both calculations?

As an example, take a look at the MIP example problem from the cvxpy website with some added constraint 'x[0]>=2':

```
np.random.seed(0)
m, n= 40, 25
A = np.random.rand(m, n)
b = np.random.randn(m)
# Construct a CVXPY problem
x = cp.Variable(n, integer=True) # x is an integer variable
obj = cp.sum_squares(A@x - b)
objective = cp.Minimize(obj)
constraint = [x[0] >= 2]
prob = cp.Problem(objective, constraint)
prob.solve()
print("The optimal value is", prob.value)
print("A solution x is")
print(x.value)

x = cp.Variable(n) # Now, x is no longer an integer variable but continuous
obj = cp.sum_squares(A@x - b) # I want to leave out this line (1)
constraint = [x[0] >= 2] # I want to leave out this line (2)
objective = cp.Minimize(obj)
prob = cp.Problem(objective, constraint)
prob.solve()
print("The optimal value is", prob.value)
print("A solution x is")
print(x.value)
```

When leaving out line (2), the problem is solved without the constraint. When leaving out line (1), the mixed integer problem is solved (so, changing 'x' to a continuous variable did not have any effect).

I want to avoid reimplementing the objective function and constraints because a missed copy and paste may lead to weird, hard-to-find errors. 
Thank you for your help!

---

Edit: Thank you, Sascha, for your reply. You are right, outsourcing the model building solves the problem. So

```
class ModelBuilder:
    m, n = 40, 25
    A = np.random.rand(m, n)
    b = np.random.randn(m)
    def __init__(self, solve_continuous):
        np.random.seed(0)
        if solve_continuous:
            self.x = cp.Variable(self.n)
        else:
            self.x = cp.Variable(self.n, integer=True)
    @staticmethod
    def constraint_func(x):
        return [x[0] >= 2]
    def objective_func(self, x):
        return cp.sum_squares(self.A@x - self.b)
    def build_problem(self):
        objective = cp.Minimize(self.objective_func(self.x))
        constraint = self.constraint_func(self.x)
        return cp.Problem(objective, constraint)

# Construct and solve mixed integer problem
build_cont_model = False
MIP_Model = ModelBuilder(build_cont_model)
MIP_problem = MIP_Model.build_problem()
MIP_problem.solve()
print("The optimal value is", MIP_problem.value)
print("A solution x is")
print(MIP_Model.x.value)

# Construct and solve continuous problem
build_cont_model = True
Cont_Model = ModelBuilder(build_cont_model)
Cont_problem = Cont_Model.build_problem()
Cont_problem.solve()
print("The optimal value is", Cont_problem.value)
print("A solution x is")
print(Cont_Model.x.value)
```

works just as expected. Since I did not have this simple idea, it shows me that I do not yet understand the concept of applying a `cvxpy.Variable` to an expression.

In my first attempt, I defined variable `x` and used it when defining `obj`. Then, I changed the value of `x` (one line before (1)). I thought that `obj` was linked to `x` by a pointer or something similar, so that it would change its behavior, as well. Apparently, this is not the case.

Do you know any resources that could help me understand this behavior? Or is it obvious to anyone that is familiar with Python? Then, where could I learn about it?

Comment: I don't follow your `When leaving out line (1), the mixed integer problem is solved (so, changing 'x' to a continuous variable did not have any effect.`, because the discrete-nature is solely implied by the defined variables and nothing else, but in regards to your question: just outsource the model-building in a class or function. A parameter `solve_continuous` or something similar is then branched on inside this function (e.g. variable definition).

Comment: Thank you a lot for your comment. Outsourcing the model-building works. This shows me that I do not yet understand the concept of applying a cvxpy.Variable. Could you help me with that? I edited my post to elaborate.

Comment: Or by using a simple function in terms of A, b, and x instead of a class: https://gist.github.com/akx/12d6b8a375282609716d723d57027754

Comment: Thank you for your shorter solution, AKX!